# Kubernetes - pod can ping other pod, but can't connect to the Redis instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, redis

I'm deploying some pods to Kubernetes for the first time, but for some reason, struggling to establish some connectivity between them.

I have a SpringBoot app that needs to connect to a Redis instance, but the SpringBoot pod can't connect to my Redis pod no matter what I do.

I can ping the Redis pod via the Redis service name in my SpringBoot pod:

```
/app # ping redis-task-queue-service
PING redis-task-queue-service (10.244.7.237): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.244.7.237: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.172 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.7.237: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms
```

But when the application actually tries to establish a connection to the Redis instance, it fails:

```
2023-06-27T01:23:37.643Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .c.s.SignalCoverageControllerApplication : Starting SignalCoverageControllerApplication v0.1.0-dev.0.uncommitted+DUST.6448.k8s.e3852e9 using Java 17-ea with PID 1 (/app/app.jar started by root in /app)
2023-06-27T01:23:37.648Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .c.s.SignalCoverageControllerApplication : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-27T01:23:38.547Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-06-27T01:23:38.551Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-27T01:23:38.599Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 26 ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
2023-06-27T01:23:39.363Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2023-06-27T01:23:39.378Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-27T01:23:39.378Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2023-06-27T01:23:39.566Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-27T01:23:39.568Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1832 ms
2023-06-27T01:23:40.872Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] a.c.c.s.config.RedisConfig               : Error trying to connect to Redis at redis-task-queue-service:6380 - Unable to connect to Redis
2023-06-27T01:23:41.450Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2023-06-27T01:23:41.464Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .c.s.SignalCoverageControllerApplication : Started SignalCoverageControllerApplication in 4.514 seconds (process running for 5.336)
2023-06-27T01:23:41.467Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.socketio.SocketIOServer              : Session store / pubsub factory used: MemoryStoreFactory (local session store only)
2023-06-27T01:23:41.495Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] a.c.c.s.r.connection.RedisConnection     : Attempting connection to Redis @ redis-task-queue-service:6380
2023-06-27T01:23:41.495Z  INFO 1 --- [ntLoopGroup-7-1] c.c.socketio.SocketIOServer              : SocketIO server started at port: 3001
2023-06-27T01:23:41.501Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] .c.s.SignalCoverageControllerApplication : No Redis instance as per configuration available to connect to. Exiting.
2023-06-27T01:23:41.582Z  WARN 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] .s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Destroy method on bean with name 'redisConnection' threw an exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.lettuce.core.api.StatefulRedisConnection.close()" because "this.connection" is null
```

Here is the output from `kubectl get svc` for the redis-task-queue-service:

```
redis-task-queue-service   ClusterIP   None             <none>        6380/TCP            15m
```

Here is the output from `kubectl get pods -o wide` for the redis-task-queue-service:

```
redis-task-queue-0                           1/1     Running   0              15m     10.244.7.237   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

Here is the redis-task-queue-service.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.taskQueueName }}-service
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.taskQueueName }}
spec:
  ports:
  - port: {{ .Values.taskQueuePort }}
    name: {{ .Values.taskQueueName }}
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.taskQueueName }}
```

Where taskQueuePort is 6380, and taskQueueName is "redis-task-queue"

Here is my controller-deployment.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: signal-coverage-controller
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: signal-coverage-controller
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: signal-coverage-controller
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: signal-coverage-controller
          image: {{ .Values.controllerImage }}
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.imagePullPolicy }}
          env:
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              value: "{{ .Values.redisHost }}"
            - name: REDIS_PORT
              value: "{{ .Values.redisPort }}"
            - name: CONTROLLER_TIMEOUT_MS
              value: "{{ .Values.controllerTimeoutMs }}"
            - name: SERVER_PORT
              value: "{{ .Values.serverPort }}"
            - name: WEBSOCKET_HOST
              value: "{{ .Values.websocketHost }}"
            - name: WEBSOCKET_PORT
              value: "{{ .Values.websocketPort }}"
          resources:
            requests:
              #cpu: {{ .Values.resources.requests.cpu }}
              memory: {{ .Values.resources.requests.memory }}
            limits:
              #cpu: {{ .Values.resources.limits.cpu }}
              memory: {{ .Values.resources.limits.memory }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
```

Where REDIS_HOST is "redis-task-queue-service" and REDIS_PORT is 6380

Comment: I see you have defined headless service. Do you have any reason for that? Can you please remove clusterIP: None and then try?

Comment: @AlokSingh I added that in because when I removed clusterIP: None earlier, I could no longer ping via the service name, i.e. "ping redis-task-queue-service", (but I could ping via the redis-task-queue pod IP) the Redis pod from my Java app pod, and also it would still show a similar "failed to connect to Redis @ redis-task-queue-service:6380" error

Comment: Another question, port mentioned in deployment (pod port) and port mentioned in Service are same? If not please use targetPort in service definition

Comment: Yes, correct, they are both 6380

the values.yaml entry for redis helm chart is: taskQueuePort: 6380, and the values.yaml entry for helm chart is redisPort: 6380

Comment: Nevermind. I now realize I wasn't passing --port 6380 to the redis-server command and it was defaulting to 6379. Whoops